# Adding java/bin path in environment variables

Tags: maven, variables, environment

I am trying to add both maven/bin and java jdk/ bin to path in environment variables . I need to add both of them but I am able to edit and add only one of them. The option to add multiple paths in path under system variables is not being open as it would for the user environment variables. Can you please suggest a solution to this?

Comment: PATH is a sequence of directories, if the UI you're using doesn't let you set it to multiple paths you'll just have to write them down yourself. The separator depends on the OS , `;` on windows and `:` on linux (and I assume MacOS)

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system's UI is just different from others but similar to mine.
The solution is very simple you need to add the paths you need in the same line separated by ; or : according to your OS.

example: `c:\sample path\maven\bin ; c:\sample path\java\bin`

I hope that your doubt is cleared.